# ¿Cómo puedo obtener los usuarios en /etc/passwd con unas características determinadas?

Tags: bash, unix, grep, procesamiento-de-texto, cut

Necesito conseguir una lista ordenada de usuarios a partir del archivo `/etc/passwd` de manera que aparezcan listados de manera ordenada aquellos usuarios que:

- Tengan un nombre de 4 letras exactamente.
- La segunda de las letras sea una vocal y las demás no.
- Cuya "shell" no sea /bin/bash

Observando el archivo `/etc/passwd` me he fijado en que los usuarios aparecen unidos por `:` a otros elementos, por ejemplo:

```
zabix:x:106:116:/lib/zabix:/bin/bash
```

A partir de ahí, he sido capaz de crear dos expresiones con `grep` para buscar lo que necesito, pero no sé cómo unirlas:

1) Para encontrar los usuarios de 4 letras y con el número de vocales y consonantes especificado:

```
grep -E '^[^a,e,i,o,u]{1}[a,e,i,o,u]{1}[^a,e,i,o,u]{1}[^a,e,i,o,u]{1}:' /etc/passwd
```

2) Para obtener aquellos usuarios cuya "shell" no es /bin/bash:

```
cut -d ':' -f 7 /etc/passwd | grep -v '/bin/bash'
```

Puede que incluso haya una manera más sencilla de dar con una sola línea de comandos que me solucione el asunto... ¿alguna idea sobre cómo unirlo o sobre qué otros comandos usar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El formato de /etc/passwd es como sigue, es decir, una serie de siete valores separador por `:`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- el nombre de usuario aparece en la primera posición.
- el nombre de la shell en la 7.ª posición.

Con todo ello, la cuestión es utilizar la herramienta que mejor permita procesar campo a campo. En este caso, parece que Awk puede resultar, pues usando el delimitador de campos ":" la tarea se vuelve trivial.

- Tengan un nombre de 4 letras exactamente.

  ```
  awk -F':' 'length($1)==4' /etc/passwd
  ```
- La segunda de las letras sea una vocal y las demás no.

  ```
  awk -F':' '$1 ~ /[^aeiouAEIOU][aeiouAEIOU][^aeiouAEIOU][^aeiouAEIOU]' /etc/passwd
  ```

  O bien puedes mirar que el 2.º carácter sea una vocal con:

  ```
  awk -F':' 'substr($0, 3, 1) ~ /[aeiouAEIOU]/'
  ```
- Cuya "shell" no sea /bin/bash

  ```
  awk -F':' '$NF != "/bin/bash"' /etc/passwd
  ```

Todo junto:

```
awk -F':' '(length($1)==4) && $1 ~ /[^aeiouAEIOU][aeiouAEIOU][^aeiouAEIOU][^aeiouAEIOU]/ && $NF != "/bin/bash"' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: Buena respuesta. Yo iba a elaborar una con `grep -P <expresion regular>` pero awk es mucho más elegante para esto